# PHP include priority

Tags: php, include

Im looking for something to prioritize my php include code. So a file that is on top of another in html will load before the one at the bottom.
For example:

```
include("file1.php");
include("file2.php");
```

They are following that order, but i want file2.php to load before file1.php.
This is incase the server is overload or slow.

Thanks in advance, Have a nice day!

Comment: Doesn't this happen automatically? PHP is an interpretative language that executes line by line so it should happen automatically.

Comment: @djthoms Considering it's procedural, I don't think so (if you mean whether it will load `file2.php` before `file1.php` if the server load is higher/slow as OP states)

Comment: @user2336174 You don't have to believe it. That's how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is procedural, which means the code is processed/run in the sequence it is written from top to bottom. If you want to conditionally include file2 before file1, you have to write some sort of method/algorithm that decides when it is appropriate to do so, and to execute the includes in the order that you want.

Comment: Hmm okey, thought there would be a easy way like in CSS (!important). Thanks for the answer! Have a nice day.